# Why does react hook form errors object temporarily empty?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to understand why the errors object in the react hook form becomes empty, even after an error is set to it. I've built a demo in a code sandbox which should help explain this much clearer.

So I have a function that runs after changing the field:

```
  const onNameChange = async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue("name", value);
    const valid = await trigger("name");
    console.log("valid", valid, "value", value);
    if (!valid) {
      return;
    }
    getPokemonDebounced(value);
    setShowPokemon(false);
  };
```

Which runs the `getPokemonDebounced` function:

```
 const getPokemon = async (input) => {
    console.log("getPokemon Fn");
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${input}`);
      console.log(res);
      const { data } = res;
      if (data) {
        setPokemon(data);
        setFetchError(null);
      }
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      setPokemon(null);
      setFetchError(error);
      setError("name", { type: "manual", message: "CUSTOM name error" });
    }
  };

  // why does the errors object temporarily become blank? nothing seems to set it to blank

  const getPokemonDebounced = useDebounce(500, getPokemon);
```

Which sets an error when an API-call fails. However, I noticed that the errors object becomes empty under this circumstance:

1. Visit the demo:
   https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-tv0cm?file=/Pokemon.js
2. Open the console (at the bottom-left of the display)
3. Type in some gibberish into the field, like 'wefhiwd'
4. Wait a moment for the errors object to log (should have a name key)
5. Type in 1 more letter into the field, and you'll see that the errors object is logged and is temporarily an empty object `{}` until the getPokemonDebounced runs and fails to fetch to set an error

My question is why does the errors object become empty `{}` again immediately after typing another letter? After typing in the initial gibberish it then set the errors object to contain an error, and I can't see how it becomes empty again temporarily.

The form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit /*, onError*/)}>
        <input
          {...register("name", { required: true })}
          name="name"
          placeholder="Enter a pokemon"
          onChange={onNameChange}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
          Show Pokemon
        </button>
        {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}
      </form>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because on change of your input, you run the validation again and it clears the errors on all valid fields.

```
  const onNameChange = async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue("name", value);
    const valid = await trigger("name"); // here you trigger validation that will clear the error if the field is valid
    console.log("valid", valid, "value", value);
    if (!valid) { // if invalid nothing happens
      return;
    }
    getPokemonDebounced(value); // if valid do the call which will set the new error on fail
    setShowPokemon(false);
  };
```

if you'd set error with name that is not associated with an input, it will persist.

```
setError("randomError", { type: "manual", message: "RANDOM name error" });
```

From the docs - https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/seterror/

```
 - This method will not persist the associated input error if the input passes validation.

 - An error that is not associated with an input field will be persisted until cleared with clearErrors.
```

Comment: Which specific part of my code runs the validation again that clears the errors? I think your suggestion of changing the name of the error works

Comment: @user8758206 I updated the answer with commented code. It seems like your validation is only `required` so anytime there is value in the field, errors get cleared. If that answers your question. Please consider marking as an anwer.